# "Flags remaining today"/"Votes remaining today" tip only displayed for the number, not for the whole caption

Tags: bug, flags, vote-to-close

If I click onto "flag" link I see the following dialog:

[image]

Note the circled part. If I move the mouse pointer to number of flags (58 in a square) I get a tip displayed but if I move the pointer to "flags remaining" there's no tip.

Initially it's one construct which purpose is to inform me that I have "58 flags remaining", it's just so formatted that the number is inside a neat colored square.

Same goes for "close" link and number of votes display.

The tip must be displayed for both the number and the "flags remaining" phrasing.